# wsdl2java - Exception class does not accept a "cause" in constructor

Tags: java, wsdl2java

I have a large WSDL file with sections including the following:

```
 <element name="fault" type="tns2:MyServiceException"/>
...
 <complexType name="MyServiceException">
  <sequence>
   <element name="subtype" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
   <element name="text" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
   <element name="type" nillable="true" type="tns2:MyServiceExceptionType"/>
  </sequence>
 </complexType>
...
    <wsdl:operation name="login">
       <wsdl:input message="impl:loginRequest" name="loginRequest"/>
       <wsdl:output message="impl:loginResponse" name="loginResponse"/>
       <wsdl:fault message="impl:MyRedirectionException" name="MyRedirectionException"/>
       <wsdl:fault message="impl:MyServiceException" name="MyServiceException"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

(I may have omitted relevant sections, sorry. Please let me know if you need more info.)

When this is run through `wsdl2java`, it generates the following exception class:

```
/**
 * MyServiceException.java
 *
 * This file was auto-generated from WSDL
 * by the Apache Axis 1.4 Feb 10, 2009 (11:08:57 GMT) WSDL2Java emitter.
 */

package my.webservice.common;

public class MyServiceException  extends org.apache.axis.AxisFault  implements java.io.Serializable {
    private java.lang.String subtype;

    private java.lang.String text;

    private my.webservice.common.MyServiceExceptionType type;

    public MyServiceException() {
    }

    public MyServiceException(
           java.lang.String subtype,
           java.lang.String text,
           my.webservice.common.MyServiceExceptionType type) {
        this.subtype = subtype;
        this.text = text;
        this.type = type;
    }
...
```

This class does not accept a "cause" as a constructor argument (and the no-args constructor of AxisFault calls "initCause(null)", so I can't use "initCause").

I would like to be able to pass in a cause when throwing exceptions of this type in my server code.

How can I configure `wsdl2java` to generate a constructor which accepts a cause?